# Statistics of zoom region

Tags: python, statistics, plotly

Does anyone know how to get the statistics such as max, min, avg values of a zoomed in region after .html plot is generated?

I want to select a area in the .html plots and then display the statistics in the cursor box or even below the chart legend.

Plot without zoom:

[image]

Plot with zoom in, here I want to show the max, min and avg value of the selected range and display it in the cursor box once hovering the data or even in any area of the plot (below the legend for example). The information should be displayed dynamically once the zoom area is selected, without re-doing the plot:

[image]

Comment: Please try to apply relevant tags to your questions. The `zoom-sdk` tag has nothing to do here. It is about the video-calling app Zoom

Comment: I don't think you can do this with Plotly's graphing library alone. You will need to use `plotly-dash` or `Plotly.js` to access the attributes of a zoomed region. If either of these work for you, I would be happy to provide a sample of what you can do

Comment: My intent is to generate an .EXE file with the Python code but I have no experience with JS, so I don't even know how to start it. I was able to create the cursors using the ipywidgets/figurewidgets but it only works running in Jupyter notebook and I can't have it working once I generate the .EXE file with the code. Is there any way to integrate the Jupyter notebook renderings capability in a .EXE file? I'm thinking If I can do it I can have Python running in the backend + the JS(html) code running in frontend (Similar to what Jupyter Notebook does directly when running in it